# Add values to table for foreign key on migration

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to put together a database migration which adds a column to a table which is a foreign key into another table, which already exists but does not contain the records that the new column will be referencing as these won't be added until the Seed() method runs at the end of the database update.

As part of the migration, I have added Sql() calls to set the appropriate values in the new column, but when AddForeignKey() is called it is failing with

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Domain.LinkedAccount_Domain.LookupItem_StatusId".
```

Presumably because the values I've added don't refer to records in the foreign key table.

Is there a [good|easy|standard] way to add the values to the foreign table as part of the migration, before the AddForeignKey() call?

Comment: add the missing values first? (maybe with two migrations)

Comment: Are the values really "appropriate"? This error usually comes from missing values. You could do an "Update-DataBase -Script" to have the SQLs for the migration available and see in SQL management studio if all values are set correctly.

Comment: I'm trying to keep it so that my colleagues just have to get the latest version of the code then run Update-Database to update their local SQL Server copies. If I'm missing some trick that can force Up-Db to run the Seed() method before running the migration then please do enlighten me,as that would be *REALLY* useful!

Comment: @StephenReindl the values are definitely the correct values, but won't get added to the "foreign" table until the Seed() method runs at the end of the update process; that's the crux of the problem.

Comment: Ok then. Please see the answer from @aSharma below. This would be my preferred method as well to insert the missing values as part of the migration patch via `Sql()` calls.

Comment: Reams of SQL in the migration was kind of what I was trying to avoid. Sadly it looks like I might not be able to :-(

Answer (score 2):

In the migration file, add the data to foreign key table first. Then you can use join to get the value of newly inserted values

```
Sql("insert into foreignKeyTable");
Sql("insert into mainTable");
```

you can use something like this for mainTable inserts, to get the ids of newly inserted data.

```
insert into mainTable
select fkId, ...
from foreignKeyTable
where values in ('insertedValeue1','insertedValue2') // the new values in FK table
```